# Run ruby script in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I made a script in ruby ​​and now I need to run it in a rails application. I'm a little lost, but I have a controller, and wanted through a GET /service /:id returns the result of this script. How can I do this?

Comment: Can't you make a class out of it, then load it as a part of environment and use?

Comment: If you don't want to do @SergioTulentsev solution you can always run the script using exec http://mentalized.net/journal/2010/03/08/5_ways_to_run_commands_from_ruby (but his solution is better)

Comment: I see that I have little basis in rails, the best would be to create a method in the helper and then run it correct? EDIT: I just saw that helpers only works for views! And for controllers?

Comment: @AnthonySewr And for controllers... Look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the comments, it seems like you want to make this into a method you can call from your controller.

Simple.

Define the method in the corresponding Model for the Controller you're calling it from (or whatever Model you wish to define the method in) and then call it from the Controller.

Say you have a ScriptRunner model, and you want to call this from the show action of some controller.

In your ScriptRunner model, simply do

```
def runscript(id)
...
end
```

and in your controller, do

```
def show
  ScriptRunner.runscript(params[:id])
  @service = Service.find_by_id(params[:id])
end
```

..or whatever you want it to do.

Answer (score 2):

Sergio Tulentsev approach is correct, Just make a model class out of it and call the model method from your controller.

Alternatively which is wrong and hacky you can just call your ruby script directly from the controller

```
def get
  @results = system "ruby your_ruby_script.rb" 
end
```